# LIKE pattern for kazakh symbols

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-like, collation

I'm trying to select names that contain Kazakh characters with this query:

```
select * from tbl where FirstName like N'%[ӘәҒғҚқҢңӨөҰұҮүҺһІі]%'
```

It's working properly for some names, but not for the 'Ә' symbol. For example, `name = 'ӘСЕМ'` is not found by the pattern `like N'%[Ә]%'` but the pattern `like N'%Ә%'` is working fine.

Why doesn't the pattern with square brackets (`like N'%[Ә]%'`) work for the `'Ә'` symbol?

Comment: Great! It working fine! Please, post your answer and I mark it like answer. And thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the collation explicitly:

```
select * from tbl 
where FirstName like N'%[ӘәҒғҚқҢңӨөҰұҮүҺһІі]%' COLLATE Kazakh_90_CI_AS
```

To list the collations available on your instance of SQL Server, see [sys.fn_helpcollations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms187963.aspx):

```
SELECT Name, Description FROM fn_helpcollations();
```